Minted in headings: the delimiters are still there
When using the minted package, I utilize delimiters that allow some otherwise prohibited characters. However, when I use \mintinline within a heading, the delimiters are not removed in the table of contents:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\mintinline{c}|foo|}
\section{\mintinline{c}@bar@}
\section{\mintinline{c}{baz}}

\end{document}

Is that a bug? It could have been a feature if at least the two unescaped chars had the same font and size...
I also tested with \lstinline and it works without issue.
Is there any workaround?

Don't you get an error from that code?

See https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/362#issuecomment-1499871446

this must be the third question you asked  that arises as basically you can not use verb commands in the argument of another command. In some cases you may accidentally not get an error and in some of those cases the output may be as desired but \mintinline , \lstinline, \verb, .... are all the same here

@DavidCarlisle I am starting to understand that, but it is a bit frustrating that only some cases, not obvious, not well documented may arises. Finding workarounds, is time consuming. I am just trying to cover my use cases, and putting code in sections is one of them.

No there are probably solutions on the tex side, but simply asking the same question over and over with marginally different examples doesn't really help. Also examples where the code is just baz doesn't help either as the solution in such a case is just to use \texttt{baz}  That is often the real answer to real questions where uses have found \verb and use it everywhere as a font change when they really should use \texttt  I suspect that that is not your situation but hard to guess what you do actually need.

I have a MkDocs web documentation with over 500 pages that I want to convert into a book. The content is written in Markdown, then converted to HTML and LaTeX. Existing tools like Pandoc don't support all MkDocs features, so I developed my own LaTeX generator in Python. My goal is smooth generation, but I encounter many LaTeX limitations requiring workarounds. Using listings or minted for code examples is not ideal due to their limitations. The best solution might be to handle syntax highlighting on the Python side and avoid relying on those packages or \verb.
